# How to remove AV Security Suite

Tags: windows, security, virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

I've been hit by this one three times in the last 3 weeks. It just suddenly pops up with a scan and freezes out every function on my system. I'm running AVG virus scan, (up to date), and even Spybot Search and Destroy, with Immunize on, and still this thing got me again today.

I've been quickly fixing it by shutting down the system and doing a system restore from command prompt. then I scan everything again and all is fine. But once again this AV security suite pops back(a week later), even with the other protection. Today it just popped up suddenly while I was eating lunch. I couldn't even go to websites to search for another fix.

Any ideas?  And at this point and after this many years of dealing with this type of attack how come there aren't so many more of these crooks in jail?

Answer (score 3):

Scan with Malware Bytes Anti Malware ([MBAM](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php)) This has removed AV Security Suite for me several times. It has a free and paid for version. The free version should do. First run a quick scan, then run a full scan.

After it's removed, remove AVG and reinstall, there's nothing left of it at this moment...

Answer (score 2):

Malware Bytes Anti Malware is a great program.

AVG used to be awesome, but the last few upgrades have left a sour taste in my mouth. Surprisingly, Microsoft Security Essentials is a really well-written program. I'm usually against anything Microsoft for my own reasons, but have to give credit where credit is due.

I suggest scanning with MBAM, remove AVG, install MS Security Essentials, do a full scan, and let it run in the background to monitor in real time. It is much less hardware-intensive and should catch anything. If AV Security Suite is still there after that, you can also try Lavasoft Ad-Aware (not my first choice anymore) as well as CCleaner to get rid of temporary files and clean up the registry.